Could not find method dependencies() for arguments on object of type org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginManagementSpec

Could not find method dependencies() for arguments [settings_cn0h89kgygs6v1tnoowf6zgq6$_run_closure1$_closure5@45f4580] on object of type org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginManagementSpec.

I got this error for below code
setting.gradle file
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools:r8:8.2.24")
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.2"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.10" apply false

}

include ":app"

What should I use instead of the dependency method?
I hope I will get a solution. Thank You
